# Conditionally sync two fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because of reasons, I've found myself in a situation where I need to conditionally sync two fields. The existing environment is heavily dependent on jQuery, but assume nothing else is already available. Effectively, I have two input fields. For the sake of discussion, we'll call them "field1" and "field2". Both are basic text input fields, both start empty, and both are editable. The goal is to make it such that if the values of the two fields are the same when you start typing in either field, the content of the fields stays in sync. If either field is different, only the focussed field is changed. I've been experimenting with doing a simpler one-way sync, but I'm running into an issue with even that. I'm also sure I'm gonna feel really dumb when someone points out the issue to me.

To clarify, the following scenarios should be considered.

- If `field1` is edited and `field1` == `field2`, `field2` should also be updated
- If `field2` is edited and `field2` == `field1`, `field1` should also be updated
- If `field1` is edited and `field1` != `field2`, `field2` should not be changed
- If `field2` is edited and `field2` != `field1`, `field1` should not be changed

**Edit:**

My original clarification (and the original idea) is dumb... it won't work without a separate interaction to specify which value is changeable at any given moment. New scenarios as follows:

- If both fields are empty and either is edited, both should be updated
- Any other scenario only the focused field should be updated

**Edit 2:**

I tried to get *way* too clever with this. It's a fatal flaw. The reality is I looked at the whole problem wrong. `field1` will be entered first 99% of the time. I've rewritten the code so that whenever `field1` is edited, it updates the placeholder for `field2`. If no data is entered in `field2`, the system pulls from `field1`. That simple. Don't try to get unnecessarily clever, kids. It never ends well.

The following is a stripped-down version of what I'm currently working with and a demo is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wvknyrc/2/).

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="field1" data-sync="#field2" id="field1" value="">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label for="field2">Field 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="field2" data-sync="#field1" id="field2" value="">
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var Sync_Demo;

    Sync_Demo = {
        init : function () {
            $('#field1').on('focusin', function() {
                Sync_Demo.sync( $(this), $('#field2') );
            });
        },
        sync : function ( source, dest ) {
            if ( source.val() === dest.val() ) {
                source.on('input', function () {
                    dest.val(source.val());
                });
            }
        },
    };
    Sync_Demo.init();
});
```

Comment: So, the both inputs are empty in the beginning, after the first character you type in one of the input, another input would updated to the same character. After that,, since both inputs are not empty, only the focused field would be updated now??

Comment: Let me be the first here to admit, that there's not much logic in what you're trying to do. Either your question is miswrote, or you're trying to achieve an impossible task.. Are you falling into [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) perhaps?

Comment: This question is really difficult to read because you seem to keep changing the requirements. Also, _" I've rewritten the code so that whenever `field1` is edited, it updates the placeholder for `field2`"_ doesn't seem correct. Your JSFiddle doesn't update any placeholder attributes. I recommend you edit your question to include *only* your current requirements, or simply delete this question and post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-question. The client asked for something that was literally impossible and I spent way too long trying to square the circle before realizing how stupid the request was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Store the old value in `beforeinput event` and compare the old value in `input event`.

```js
$("input").on("beforeinput", function (e) {
    $(this).data("old-value", e.target.value);
});

$("input").on("input", function (e) {
    const syncTarget = $($(this).data("sync-target"));
    if (syncTarget.data("old-value") === $(this).data("old-value")) { 
        const newValue = e.target.value;
        syncTarget.val(newValue);
        syncTarget.data("old-value",newValue);
    }
});

$("#btn1").on("click", function () {
    $("#field1").val("555");
    $("#field1").data("old-value", "555");
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function () {
    $("#field2").val("55");
    $("#field2").data("old-value", "55");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="field1" data-sync-target="#field2" data-old-value="" placeholder="field1">
<input id="field2" data-sync-target="#field1" data-old-value="" placeholder="field2">

<button id="btn1">change field1</button>
<button id="btn2">change field2</button>
```

Comment: Same problem as the previous answer (it was so close, I wish it hadn't been removed). Look at the clarification in the question. I need bi-directional sync based on the state of both fields at the time one field is focused.

Comment: @Evertiro, Cloud you provide a situation my answer doesn't fit your requirement?

Comment: Correction, your snippet does exactly what I asked... I just realized I asked the wrong thing. There's a flaw in my original theory - it makes it effectively impossible to change either value independently without the buttons you added, and I can't do that. Seems I need to rethink for a moment.

Comment: Ok, scenarios updated. Sometimes I try to be too clever.